# Jest cannot find module 'got' from node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm getting an error from one of my (previously working) tests when I run `yarn jest`:

> Cannot find module 'got' from 'src/rss/queries.ts'

I've added `got` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "got": "^12.0.0",
}
```

My `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts(|x)'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.ts', '!.webpack/**/*'],
  verbose: true,
}
```

I'm using `got` in `./src/rss/queries.ts`:

```
import * as got from 'got'
```

I've also tried:

```
import { got, RequestError } from 'got'
```

In both cases the application works - I can see `got` making requests via the application logs (and vscode is indicating the correct path to the module in `node_modules` when I hover over the above). So it's definitely there, and working.

But `jest` can't find it. Why? It's not an uncommon stackoverflow question, but they all seem to relate to importing custom local modules via relative paths, etc. I'm just trying to use one out of `node_modules`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 12 of got doesn't work with jest. Best to use version 11 for now. See the details in the release notes at: https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/releases/tag/v12.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to find a reason for, or solution to, this. Ended up swapping `got` for `axios`, which is a shame as I liked many `got` features.